# replace rows by ID

Tags: r

I have two data frames `full`:

```
library(dplyr)

full %>% glimpse()
Observations: 2,919
Variables: 10
$ Id           <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15...
$ BsmtQual     <fct> Gd, Gd, Gd, TA, Gd, Gd, Ex, Gd, TA, TA, TA, Ex, T...
$ BsmtCond     <fct> TA, TA, TA, Gd, TA, TA, TA, TA, TA, TA, TA, TA, T...
$ BsmtExposure <fct> No, Gd, Mn, No, Av, No, Av, Mn, No, No, No, No, N...
$ BsmtFinType1 <fct> GLQ, ALQ, GLQ, ALQ, GLQ, GLQ, GLQ, ALQ, Unf, GLQ,...
$ BsmtFinSF1   <int> 706, 978, 486, 216, 655, 732, 1369, 859, 0, 851, ...
$ BsmtFinType2 <fct> Unf, Unf, Unf, Unf, Unf, Unf, Unf, BLQ, Unf, Unf,...
$ BsmtFinSF2   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ BsmtUnfSF    <int> 150, 284, 434, 540, 490, 64, 317, 216, 952, 140, ...
$ TotalBsmtSF  <int> 856, 1262, 920, 756, 1145, 796, 1686, 1107, 952, ...
```

And this one `dat1`

```
dat1 %>% glimpse()
Observations: 88
Variables: 10
$ Id           <int> 18, 40, 91, 103, 157, 183, 260, 333, 343, 363, 37...
$ BsmtQual     <fct> No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, N...
$ BsmtCond     <fct> No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, N...
$ BsmtExposure <fct> No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, N...
$ BsmtFinType1 <fct> No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, N...
$ BsmtFinSF1   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ BsmtFinType2 <fct> No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, N...
$ BsmtFinSF2   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ BsmtUnfSF    <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ TotalBsmtSF  <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
```

I want to replace the rows in `full` with the rows of `dat1` by matching Id. I tried it with `merge` and `tidyverse` but it didn't work.

Comment: You could just do `full[match(dat1$id, full$id),] <- dat1`.

Comment: I found a post where I saw this solution, but strangely it didn't work.

Comment: It probably didn't work because you have factor columns. Note the warning messages when you run `bind_rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use combination of `anti_join` and `semi_join` and then merge using `bind_rows`. The below solution will provide desired records.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(anti_join(full, dat1, by="ID"), semi_join(dat1, full, by="ID"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQLDF library in R and make inner join on id between full and data1. select the variables from the Full data frame.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use `rbind` or `cbind` (hard to tell without a running example):

```
## Combining by columns (what seems to be your case)
combined <- cbind(full, dat1)
## Combining by rows
combined <- rbind(full, dat1)
```

Comment: I tried it this way but then I have duplicated rows - the same thing with  as with 'merge`